# Adaptec 52445 RAID controller error 418: Bad block discovered, but which drive?

Tags: raid-controller, adaptec

I started getting emails from this old controller last week, but they're not very descriptive:

```
May 17, 2017 4:58:32 AM MDT WRN      418:A01C-S--L--    REDACTED_SERVER_NAME    Bad Block discovered: controller 1 (39369000).
```

Notably there is no indication of which drive is having problems.  I also found a corresponding entry in the windows event log, with Event ID 418, but it had only the same sparse information.  How do you figure out which drive is having issues?

Answer (score 1):

After a bunch of searching, I was able to track down the fact that this controller writes more information into a separate error log named `RaidEvtA.log` that it stores in its own location.  In my case, this file was in the `C:\ProgramData\Adaptec\Adaptec Storage Manager` folder.  This file contained the following entry corresponding to this error:

```
May 17, 2017 4:58:32 AM MDT INF                     REDACTED_SERVER_NAME    Sense data: Medium error (UNRECOVERED READ ERROR). Controller 1, channel 0, SCSI device ID 8, LUN 0, cdb [88 00 00 00 00 00 39 36 90 00 00 00], data [70 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 11 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00]  
May 17, 2017 4:58:32 AM MDT WRN                     REDACTED_SERVER_NAME    Medium error: controller 1, channel 0, SCSI device ID 8, LUN 0, start LBA 39369000, end LBA 393691ff, bad block recovery possible
```

The crucial piece of information in this case is the SCSI device ID (8 in this case), which the UI for the controller shows when you look at the properties for the physical drives.  I'll likely need this information again, and hopefully this will help some other poor soul with this controller or a similar one.